# Using AngularJS to buld quicklaunch menu on Sharepoint App - How to indent some options and disable clicking on menu headers

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sharepoint

I am following PluralSight course by Andrew Connell about building SPAs as Sharepoint Apps, in this he explains how to bind the route config options to a controller for the quick launch.

I understand this perfectly fine but I need 2 additional things that I am not sure how to do:
1.  Some options of the menu, are just headers, should be bolded and without a link.
2. And the options below the header should be indented a little bit to the right of the header.

this is my config.route.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('app');

  // get all the routes
  app.constant('routes', getRoutes());

  // config routes & their resolvers
  app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);

  function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {
    routes.forEach(function (route) {
      $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }

  // build the routes
  function getRoutes() {
    return [
      {
        url: '/',
        config: {
          templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          title: 'Pagina Inicial',
          settings: {
            nav: 0,
            content: 'dashboard',
            quickLaunchEnabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        url: '/LearningPaths',
        config: {
          templateUrl: 'app/learningPath/learningPaths.html',
          title: 'Comites',
          settings: {
            nav: 1,
            content: 'Comites',
            quickLaunchEnabled: true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        url: '/LearningPaths/:id',
        config: {
          templateUrl: 'app/learningPath/learningPathsDetail.html',
          title: 'Calendario Comites',
          settings: {
            nav: 1.1,
            content: 'Calendario Comites',
            quickLaunchEnabled: true
          }
        }
      },
       {
           url: '/LearningPaths/:id',
           config: {
               templateUrl: 'app/learningPath/learningPathsDetail.html',
               title: 'Docs Comites',
               settings: {
                   nav: 1.2,
                   content: 'Docs Comites',
                   quickLaunchEnabled: true
               }
           }
       },
       {
        url: '/LearningItems',
        config: {
          templateUrl: 'app/learningItem/learningItems.html',
          title: 'Dir Estrategica',
          settings: {
            nav: 2,
            content: 'Dir Estrategica',
            quickLaunchEnabled: true
          }
        }
       },
       {
           url: '/LearningItems',
           config: {
               templateUrl: 'app/learningItem/learningItems.html',
               title: 'Vista General',
               settings: {
                   nav: 2.1,
                   content: 'Vista General',
                   quickLaunchEnabled: true
               }
           }
        },
        {
            url: '/LearningItems',
            config: {
                templateUrl: 'app/learningItem/learningItems.html',
                title: 'Mis Vistas',
                settings: {
                    nav: 2.2,
                    content: 'Mis Vistas',
                    quickLaunchEnabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        {
             url: '/LearningItems',
             config: {
                 templateUrl: 'app/learningItem/learningItems.html',
                 title: 'Docs Estrategia',
                 settings: {
                     nav: 2.3,
                     content: 'Docs Estrategia',
                     quickLaunchEnabled: true
                 }
             }
         }
    ];
  }
})();
```

my quicklaunch template

```
<div data-ng-controller="quicklaunch as vm"
     id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
  <div class="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">
    <a id="startNavigation" name="startNavigation"></a>
    <div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
      <div class="noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
        <ul class="noindex ms-core-listMenu-root static">
          <li class="static" data-ng-repeat="route in vm.navRoutes" data-ng-class="{selected: vm.isCurrent(route)}">
            <a href="#{{route.url}}"
               data-ng-bind-html="route.config.settings.content"
               class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"
               data-ng-class="{selected:vm.isCurrent(route), 'ms-core-listMenu-selected':vm.isCurrent(route)}"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the quicklaunch controller

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // define controller
  var controllerId = 'quicklaunch';
  angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$route', 'config', 'common', 'routes', quickLaunch]);

  // init controller
  function quickLaunch($route, config, common, routes) {
    var vm = this;
    // utility method to see if the provided route is the current route
    vm.isCurrent = isCurrent;

    // init controller
    init();

    // init controller
    function init() {
      common.logger.log("controller loaded", null, controllerId);
      getNavigationRoutes();
    }

    // #region private members
    // load all navigatino routes
    function getNavigationRoutes() {
      // only retrieve routes flagged quickLaunchEnabled = true & sort them
      vm.navRoutes = routes.filter(function(route) {
        return route.config.settings && route.config.settings.nav && route.config.settings.quickLaunchEnabled;
      }).sort(function(routeA, routeB) {
        return routeA.config.settings.nav > routeB.config.settings.nav;
      });
    }

    // utility method to see if the provided route is the current route
    function isCurrent(route) {
      if (!route.config.title || !$route.current || !$route.current.title) {
        return '';
      }
      var menuName = route.config.title;
      return $route.current.title.substr(0, menuName.length) === menuName ? 'current' : '';
    }
    // #endroute
  }
})();
```

Comment: If I remove the url or comment it out from the routes config, when I click on It, I get the working on it popup and never dismisses.

Comment: The issue is it's doing an ng-repeat against a single-level of routes, hence you only get one level of menu items with no indentation.

Comment: indentation is not mandatory, at least I should be able to disable the clicking on the menu header and make them bolded for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that CSS should be able to handle most of those needs.

1) header entries only: I'm assuming that "nav: 0" or "quickLaunchEnabled: false" are your flags for top level items, you can use that to assign a class of something like 'toplevel' to it w/ Javascript and then have the CSS for that defined as:

```
.toplevel {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

2) options indented. Again, you should be able to do this with CSS. Take

```
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox (or whatever your class is to start the indent with)
{
padding-left: 34px;
border-left-style: none;
}
```